# Datatype for indexing vector

Tags: rust

I just started to learn Rust. I understand that Rust's **for loop indices** and **vector indices** must be of type `usize`, hence I have written the following code. The computation of `j` within the for loop requires `i` to be type `u32`, so I convert it. Now, I have to change the type of `i` and `j` again to get the vector items.

I would like to avoid this constant back-and-forth conversion, is there an alternate way to do this in Rust? Thank you for your help.

```
fn compute(dots: Vec, N: u32) -> f32 {
    
    let mut j: u32;
    let mut value: f32 = 0.0;
    
    for i in 0..N {
        j = (i as u32 + 1) % N;
        value += dots[i as usize].a * dots[j as usize].b;
        value -= dots[i as usize].b * dots[j as usize].a;
    }
    
    return value
}
```

Comment: use dots.get() instead of indexing, get(index) returns a Option you have to unwrap it

Comment: What is the question? Whether it's possible to index into vectors with a type other than `usize`? If so: No. As for general ergonomics: What about about `let M = N as usize` once and for all, and then letting `i` and `j` also be `usize`s in a loop over `0..M`?

(In real code you should make sure that you know that `usize` is at least as wide as `u32` on the given platform, or if you can't assure that, at least convert with `try_into`, but that's besides the core topic here)

Comment: Thank you @gspr, ergonomics was the question here. Setting **N** to be type ```usize``` solved the problem.

Comment: OK, I've turned my comment into an actual answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change the function signature to use `N: usize`, or, if you can't do that, just `let M = N as usize` and loop over `0..M` (the loop variable will then have type `usize`).

Be aware that in real code, you need to be sure that `usize` is at least as wide as `u32` if you opt for the conversion. If you cannot assure that, use `try_into` instead of `as` to convert.

Comment: ...or even `let N = N as usize`.

Comment: ...or even `for i in 0..N as usize` ;)